# why my code is not filtering the array?what am i missing?

Tags: javascript, html

Here is the code
HTML:

```
<form>
<input type = "text" id="searchTerm" onChange="onSearchChange(this.value)" />
 </form>
<div id = "root"></div>
```

Javascript:
List and variables declaration:

```
 var searchItem="";
        var isFiltered;
        const list = [
  {
    title: 'React',
url: 'https://facebook.github.io/react/',
author: 'Jordan Walke',
num_comments: 3,
points: 4,
objectID: 0,
},
{
title: 'Redux',
url: 'https://github.com/reactjs/redux',
author: 'Dan Abramov, Andrew Clark',
num_comments: 2,
points: 5,
objectID: 1,
},
]
```

function for input field event 'onchange':

```
function onSearchChange(value){   
searchItem = value;
}
```

map function for extrating object properties:

```
function extractProps(items){
    var x = "<div> <span>" +items.title+", </span> <span>"+items.author +"<span></div>"
    return x;
}
```

main function:

```
function myFunc(){
    document.getElementById('root').innerHTML = "";
    var y= list.filter( isFiltered = searchItem => (item) => item.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchItem.toLowerCase())).map(extractProps).join("");
    document.getElementById('root').innerHTML = y;
     alert(y);
}
myFunc()
```

Comment: you're passing a function that returns a function as the argument to `list.filter` ... a function is an object, an object is truthy - and why are you saving that callback function into a variable `isFiltered`??

Comment: Oh I see what you're doing ... you think `searchItem` in `onSearchChange` is somehow related to `searchItem` in `isFiltered = searchItem => (item)` ... and that chainging `searchItem` will magically re-run the filter inside `myFunc` which actually on ever runs once

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
By using $.map() you can achieve this.
Provide array of objects(here list) and call back function.

function myFunc(){
    var fillteredArr = $.map( list, function( val, i ) {
         if(val.title.toLowerCase() == searchItem.toLowerCase())
            return val;
    });
    return fillteredArr;
}

The function myFunc() will return the filltered array of objects.
```

Comment: so, add jquery library, rewrite code to use jquery map instead of array map ... and this fixes the problem? wow!!

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to run myFunc every time `onSearchChange` is called, not just once

Also, in `.filter(fn)`, `fn` is a function that returns truthy/falsey - whereas in your code it returns a function, which is truthy, and the inner function never runs

Also, the `var searchItem` is totally unrelated to the argument name `searchItem` in your filter callback function

```
function onSearchChange(value){   
    myFunc(value);
}

function myFunc(searchItem = ""){
    document.getElementById('root').innerHTML = "";
    var y= list.filter( item => item.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchItem.toLowerCase())).map(extractProps).join("");
    document.getElementById('root').innerHTML = y;
}
```

note 1: you could of course `onChange="myFunc(this.value)"` instead of calling a function that calls a function with exactly the same arguments

note 2: no need for `var searchItem` or `isFiltered` (what was that for anyway?)

as a bonus, all of it rewritten in a more modern style and proper indentation to make it readable

```js
const list = [{
  title: 'React',
  url: 'https://facebook.github.io/react/',
  author: 'Jordan Walke',
  num_comments: 3,
  points: 4,
  objectID: 0,
}, {
  title: 'Redux',
  url: 'https://github.com/reactjs/redux',
  author: 'Dan Abramov, Andrew Clark',
  num_comments: 2,
  points: 5,
  objectID: 1,
}];

const extractProps = ({title, author}) => `<div><span>${title}, </span> <span>${author}<span></div>`;

document.getElementById('searchTerm').addEventListener('change', function() {
  myFunc(this.value.toLowerCase());
});
const myFunc = (searchItem = '') => document.getElementById('root').innerHTML = list
  .filter(item => item.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchItem))
  .map(extractProps)
  .join("");


myFunc();
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" id="searchTerm" />
</form>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: var y= list.filter( (item) => item.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchItem.toLowerCase())).map(extractProps).join("") 
in this line it gives an error : searchItem is not defined

Comment: You're right - because you call myFunc without an argument (something I didn't notice at first)

Comment: Yes you're right, when i first call myFunc i was not passing any arguments to it that's why it was giving undefined. I have to pass an empty string as an argument first. Thanks for your help i understand now.

Comment: or you can use a default value `const myFunc = (searchItem = '')`